# MongoDB&JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, out-of-memory

The data size in telemetry table is HUGE. So, I get "JavaScript heap out of memory" error.
How do I overcome that error?

```
const aloUrl = `mongodb://${userName}:${pwd}@${host}:${port}/${dbName}`;
MongoClient.connect(aloUrl, function(err, client) {
if (err) {
return console.log('ERROR:: ', err);
}
console.log("INFO:: OK");
const db = client.db(dbName);

var arr = db.collection('endpoint').find({provider:"KMR"}).map(e => e._id).toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err){

        console.log("ERROR", err)
    }

        var son = db.collection('telemetry').find({endpoint: {$in: result}}).toArray().then(arr =>{

            console.log("Let's start to party")
            for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                console.log("\t" + arr[i]._id)
            }

        }).catch(e => {

            console.log(`ERROR::${e}`)
        })

})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the mongodb docs,

> The toArray() method returns an array that contains all the documents
>   from a cursor. The method iterates completely the cursor, loading all
>   the documents **into RAM and exhausting the cursor**.

Thus instead of calling `toArray`, you should use the `next` or `forEach` (or some other method which doesn't load everything at once to RAM), to iterate through the elements one by one.

For example, to print all the documents in your telemetry collection ONE BY ONE, you can do this,

```
db.collection('telemetry')
    .find({
        endpoint: {
            $in: result
        }
    })
    .forEach((document) => {
        console.log(document)
    });
```

Comment: can you share a sample code that tells you how to use it? I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `forEach` instead of `toArray`in order to fetch and load w/o exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

For huge data it's always advised to stream (it's achieved by cursor in mongo).

also

> $lookup is new in MongoDB 3.2. It performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the “joined” collection for processing.

You can have a look at [aggregation pipeline for mongo](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/aggregation/)

updating your code with aggregate.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// Connection URL
const aloUrl    = `mongodb://${userName}:${pwd}@${host}:${port}/${dbName}`;
MongoClient.connect(aloUrl, function (err, client) {
    console.log("INFO:: OK");
    const db   = client.db(dbName);
    const col  = db.collection('endpoint');
    var cursor = col.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {provider: "KMR"}
        },
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from        : "telemetry",
                    localField  : "_id",
                    foreignField: "endpoint",
                    as          : "telemetry"
                }
        }
    ]);
    console.log("Let's start to party")
    cursor.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("\t" + data._id)
    });
    cursor.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Done ");
    });
});
```

Comment: cursor.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data); // => it does not enter this area.
    });   ', function () {
I could not get it working. It does not print on the screen. This is how the screen comes out.
INFO:: OK
Done

Comment: INFO:: OK
Let's start to party
Done
sorry. It did not work.

cursor.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("\t" + data._id)
    });

This function is not working at all.

Comment: there might be data issue, please verify if data is present. collection "endpoint" should have provider as KMR and collection "telemetry" should have endpoint with Id of endpoint. also, Both localfield(_id) & foreignField should be of same type i.e. string/object.

Comment: endpoint._id = telemetry.endpoint

the structure is this way.

Comment: what are the types of endpoint._id & telemetry.endpoint are they both objectId or one of them is string. check your mongoose schema.